# Error resolve: com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1

Tags: android

When I try the Library resolve: com.roughike: bottom-bar: 1.4.0.1, I get an error
I would be grateful if the tips that should I do?

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maleki.royalvas.rbottom"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Error:**

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1

Comment: Sync your Gradle Files https://cdn.mxpnl.com/cache/9c6b87fa232699502a8eaa2e4dba0dfc/images/help/android-sync-gradle.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , in your top **build.gradle**  (not which one in the app module , you will find in project module) , inside `allprojects` add `jcenter()` . 
So it should be look like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Then sync your project .

Comment: What should be used instead now that jcenter is being shutdown?